# Showing triangular region is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I'm trying to show that the region $R = \{(x,y) \in (a,b)\times(a,b) : x<y \}$ as a subset of $R^2$ is connected. I've tried to do this by showing that it is path-connected, (it clearly is) but how do I actually show that if I take two points in this region and join them with a straight line, the straight line will be contained completely in $R$?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, given two points $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ in $R$ you want to connect them by a straight line. So define $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $\gamma(t) = (x+t(x'-x),y+t(y'-y))$. This is the straight line you wanted, in the form of a path. It is clearly continuous as a function of $t$ and goes from $(x,y)$ to $(x',y')$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. All you need to show is that each point lies in $R$ for gamma to be a path in $R$.

Comment: That is precisely the bit I am struggling with!

Comment: Okay, so can you show that if $x,x' \in (a,b)$ then for $t \in (0,1)$, $tx'+(1-t)x \in (a,b)$? Similarly, if $x<y$ and $x'<y'$, can you show that $tx'+(1-t)x < ty'+(1-t)y$?

Comment: Ah yes I see that now, thanks

Comment: @Wooster No problem! In general, connecting two things by a straight line (in any vector space) is known as interpolation, and will always map convex sets to themselves. You might like to try and see if you can show that the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$, ($[0,1]^n$), or even the unit ball ($\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| \leq 1\}$) is path connected using a similar interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\boldsymbol R$ and $\boldsymbol R_+$ are connected, $\tilde R:=\boldsymbol R\times\boldsymbol R_+$ is connected.  Define the linear map $A\colon\boldsymbol R^2\to\boldsymbol R^2$ to rotate $\tilde R$ counterclockwise by $\pi/4$ via
$$A=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Thus $R=A(\tilde R)$ is connected as $A$ is continuos.